# Word meaning - "across"

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary

Sometimes I *get across* the word "across". And I know it means "from one side to the other". But, could you guys explain me the meaning of it, in these examples? Because they don't seem to follow this meaning:

> She sits *across* the aisle.
>
> They walked *across*.
>
> He takes off his shirt. Dots of lake water glisten in the sun *across* his back.

I thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"[Across](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/across)" also means "on the opposite side of".

> She sits across the aisle. - She is sitting on the opposite side.
>
> They walked across. - Walked from this side to the other side.
>
> Dots of lake water glisten in the sun across his back. - From one side of his back to the other side of his back.